# Installing rails-backbone, missing assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I just installed the `rails-backbone` gem and then `rails g backbone:install`.

I see a list of javascript references to backbone on `application.js` but it does not copy them to the project and I'm not sure if this is normal.

```
//= require backbone
//= require backbone_rails_sync
//= require backbone_datalink
//= require backbone/myapp
```

If this is normal, where is it possible to find `backbone_rails_sync` and `backbone_datalink`. I'm afraid that by simple searching will maybe not find the same version tested for this gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are inside the gem and served through Rails Asset Pipeline.

You could find them in [the gem souce](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts).

Comment: Ok, just needed to restart the server.